# How to cancel send when cancelling a dialog prompt for a folder to save a sent e-mail?

Tags: vba, outlook

I found code to ask which folder to save an e-mail when I click send. A dialogue box opens up asking where to save the sent e-mail.

Where I decide I no longer want to send the e-mail and click Cancel, rather than going back to the e-mail, I get an "IsInDefaultStore" error message that says "This function isn't designed to work with Nothing objects and will return False." Then, after clicking OK in the dialogue box, I get an error that says:

> Run-time error '91':
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

When I click Debug, the following lines are highlighted

```
If Not objFolder Is Nothing And _
          IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) And _
          objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
```

After clicking Send, I'd like to be able to click Cancel on the dialogue box that asks where to save, and go back to editing my e-mail. I would like the dialogue box to re-appear when I click Send the second time.

---

Updated code, based on comments already received:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = Application.Session
    If (objFolder Is Nothing) Then Set objFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder

If Item.Class = olMail Then
        Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
        If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function IsInDefaultStore(objOL As Object) As Boolean
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim blnBadObject As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objApp = objOL.Application
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set objNS = objApp.Session
        Set objInbox = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        Select Case objOL.Class
            Case olFolder
                If objOL.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case olAppointment, olContact, olDistributionList, _
                 olJournal, olMail, olNote, olPost, olTask
                If objOL.Parent.StoreID = objInbox.StoreID Then
                    IsInDefaultStore = True
                Else
                    IsInDefaultStore = False
                End If
            Case Else
                blnBadObject = True
        End Select
    Else
        blnBadObject = True
    End If
    If blnBadObject Then
        MsgBox "This function isn't designed to work " & _
                "with " & TypeName(objOL) & _
                " objects and will return False.", _
                , "IsInDefaultStore"
        IsInDefaultStore = False
    End If
    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objInbox = Nothing
End Function
```

Edit: I updated the code based on comments from Dmitry Streblechenko. Outlook no longer closes when I cancel the sending of an e-mail. However, rather than going back to the e-mail, it still sends the e-mail.

Edit 2: I updated the code based on comments from Dmitry Streblechenko and Tim Williams. My only issue now is when I Cancel, it still sends the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more like this:

```
Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
If objFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If IsInDefaultStore(objFolder) And objFolder.DefaultItemType = olmailitem Then
    '...etc
    '...etc
```

`And` in VBA does not short-circuit: all tests are performed, so even if `objFolder` is `Nothing` your original line still calls `IsInDefaultStore(objFolder)`

Comment: I tried this, but it stopped saving emails to the folder that was chosen, even though a box popped up. Edit - Thank you, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Possibly `Exit Sub` is not the appropriate choice of action there, but there are 3 clauses in your `If` block so it's difficult to know how they should be split so the logic still works as you intended.  Nevertheless, you still need to split out the test for `Nothing` from the other two tests which assume there is an object linked to `objFolder`

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant, but adding "Exit Sub" and getting rid of the other If statements fixed the issue to some extent. Now, if I Cancel sending an e-mail, I won't get an error message, but the e-mail still sends and saves to my Sent folder. Mostly there, but this is good progress - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code:

```
Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder
if (objFolder Is Nothing) Then set objFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
```

And get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` statement - nothing good ever comes out of it.

Comment: Thank you for this. Now if I cancel, it no longer closes Outlook. However, I still get the same error message. When I click Okay, it says: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Latest code has been added above. I've updated the original post; can't post latest code as a comment

Comment: Your code is wrong - the line that ends with "Then" needs to have the next line (calling GetDefaultFolder) on the same line. Or add "End If" after the line calling GetDefaultFolder.

Comment: Made the fixes, I no longer get an error message when I Cancel. The e-mail still sends and saves to my Sent Items folder, which is progress. Thanks again for your help. I have updated the code if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Cancel parameter in ItemSend.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = Application.Session

    If Item.Class = olMail Then

        Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder

        If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
            Set Item.SaveSentMessageFolder = objFolder
        Else
            ' Cancel ItemSend
            ' Now you must choose the save folder on every mail sent.
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End If

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Given the current state of your question there appears to be no need for the IsInDefaultStore function.